# Evaluating $\prod_{r=0}^{19} \cos\frac{(3r+1)\pi}{60}$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\prod_{r=0}^{19} \cos\frac{(3r+1)\pi}{60}$$

Firstly I am thinking about trigonometry use, but that do not work after that. I had tried using complex numbers, but I am not able to get where I am mistaken. In complex numbers, I had written that
$$\prod_{r=0}^{19} \operatorname{Re}\left( e^{i(3r+1)\pi/60)} \right)$$
Please tell where I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you think you are "wrong"?

Comment: That method is correct. Use the fact that $\Re$ and multiplication commute.

Comment: @K.defaoite It is not true that $\mathfrak{R}$ and multiplication commute. $-1=\mathfrak{R}(i\cdot i)\neq \mathfrak{R}(i)\cdot \mathfrak{R}(i)=0$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Ugh, what was I thinking? I think I somehow thought this was a summation.

Answer (score 3):

The idea to use complex numbers is a good one, but having a product of real parts leads nowhere.

I advise you to write this product in the following manner

$$A=\prod_{r=0}^{19} \cos\left(\frac{(3r+1)\pi}{60}\right)=\prod_{r=0}^{19} \frac12 \left(e^{i(3r+1)\pi/60}+e^{-i(3r+1)\pi/60}\right)$$

$$A=\frac{1}{2^{20}}\prod_{r=0}^{19} e^{i(3r+1)\pi/60} \left(1+e^{-i(3r+1)\pi/30}\right)$$

$$A=\frac{1}{2^{20}}\prod_{r=0}^{19} e^{i(3r+1)\pi/60} (-e^{-i\pi/30})\left(-e^{i\pi/30}-e^{-ir\pi/10}\right)$$

As $A$, from its original expression, is real, we can write:

$$A=\pm |A|=\pm\frac{1}{2^{20}}\prod_{r=0}^{19} \left|\left(-e^{i\pi/30}-e^{-ir\pi/10}\right)\right|\tag{1}$$

Why have we chosen to write $A$ under the somewhat complicated expression (1) ? Because we can transform (1) thanks to the following polynomial [having for its roots the twenty $20$th-roots of unity] which can be written in two ways:

$$P(z)=z^{20}-1=\prod_{r=0}^{19}\left(z-e^{-ir\pi/10}\right)\tag{2}$$

Setting $z=-e^{i\pi/30}$ in (2) transforms the product in (1) into :

$$|P(-e^{i\pi/30})|= |e^{(i\pi/30)20}-1|= |e^{2 i\pi/3}-1|=\sqrt{3}.$$

Therefore, the final result is:

$$A=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2^{20}}\approx 1.651812 \times 10^{-6}$$

with a plus sign in fact (do you see why ?).

Comment: Any comment ?...

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica*:

$$\frac{\sqrt{3} \sin ^3\left(\frac{\pi }{15}\right) \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi }{15}\right)
   \csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{30}\right) \csc \left(\frac{7 \pi }{30}\right)}{524288}$$

$$= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{1048576}$$

which has numerical value $1.65181 \cdot 10^{-6}$

Comment: Little remark: $524288=2^{19}$