# Integrate $\int \frac{x^9+16x}{x^{12}+64}\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: real-analysis

$$\int \frac{x^9+16x}{x^{12}+64}\mathrm{d}x $$
I had tried to take out common $x$ raised to some power , and tried to convert in the form of $\frac{x-1}{x}$ ; but i am not getting how I proceed further; please tell what approach I have to use to evaluate this.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2C9%5D%2B16x%2CPower%5Bx%2C12%5D%2B+64%5D%2Cx%5D) gives a result that is not too complicated, maybe you can differentiate the result to understand their approach.

Comment: You haven't made any comment about my answer to your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4616690/305862) last week. This site is based on dialog...

Comment: Yes , I got it your way .

Answer (score 2):

Set $x^2=2y\implies x\ dx=dy$

$$\int\dfrac{x(x^8+16)}{x^{12}+64}dx=\int\dfrac{y^4+1}{y^6+1}dy$$

Writing  $y^2=z$ and using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),  $$\dfrac{y^4+1}{y^6+1}=\dfrac{z^2+1}{z^3+1}=\dfrac{Az+B}{z^2-z+1}+\dfrac C{z+1}$$

$\implies(Az+B)(z+1)+C(z^2-z+1)=z^2(C+A)+z(A+B-C)+B+C$ which needs to be $=z^2+1$

Comparing the constants, $1=B+C\iff B=1-C$

Comparing the coefficients of $z^2,C+A=1\iff A=1-C$

Comparing the coefficients of $z, 0=A+B-C=1-C+1-C-C\iff C=\dfrac23$

$A=B=1-C=\dfrac13$

We can safely manage $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{C\ dy}{y^2+1}$

For $\dfrac{Az+B}{z^2-z+1},$  $$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{y^2+1}{3(y^4-y^2+1)}dy=\dfrac13\cdot\int\dfrac{1+\dfrac1{y^2}}{\left(y-\dfrac1y\right)^2+1}dy$$

as $\displaystyle\int\left(1+\dfrac1{y^2}\right)dy=?$